# Django templatetag to return the field based on field label

Tags: django, django-templates

I know the field label (lets say "BOP").  I want to create a templatetag which will return the right field object so I can use it in a form like this.

```
{% with bop=form|f_lookup:"BOP"  %}
    <div>
        <div class="span-4">BOP</div>
        <div class="span-5">{{ bop }}</div>
    </div>
{% endwith %}
```

My templatetag is not working and I know I must be overlooking something obvious..

```
@register.filter(name='f_lookup')
def field_lookup_by_label(form, arg):
    """Look up a form field based on a label"""
    return next((form.fields[k] for k, v in form.fields.items() if v.label == arg), None)
```

Comment: Function looks ok to me. Are you sure its being called? Have you loaded the custom template tag in to your template?

Comment: You're right the function appears to work, but the template appears to render the string of the class..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
return next((fld for fld in form if fld.label == arg), None)
```

If this works, then the reason is the following. `form.fields` is a dictionary of `Field` objects, which don't know how to render themselves in templates. It's only when you call the form's `__getitem__` function that a field is converted to a `BoundField` object, which knows how to render itself as HTML. See lines 101 and 412 of https://github.com/django/django/blob/master/django/forms/forms.py.

When you return an element of `form.fields`, you're just returning a `Field` subclass, instead of a `BoundField`, and only `BoundField` objects know how to render themselves in a template.

Also, I believe that your original function won't work if you don't pass a label as a keyword argument to your bop field constructor. The label of a `Field` object will be `None` if the constructor was called with `label=None`. When the `BoundField` object is constructed, the label is taken from the field's label, or from the field's name if `label` is `None`.

Comment: Kudos to you!  Congratulations you nailed it.  FWIW I was literally coming to the same understanding.  Really good job from a n00b to SO.  Welcome aboard!  Also if you're looking for work I could use some help!